`git rev-list --grep` only first line of commit message
Consider a git history with the following two commits (among others).
Fix-123 - Fix Foo

Foo was broken. This change fixes it.

Fix-456 - Fix Bar

Fix-123 broke Bar. This change fixes it.

Is it possible to use the --grep flag of git rev-list to find only commits whose messages begin with Fix-123? Using the anchor ^ alone isn't sufficient, since by default git interprets this as the beginning of a line, not the beginning of the entire message. So for example git rev-list --grep "^Fix-123" will match both of the above commits, since the second line of the commit for Fix-456 also begins with Fix-123.
I realize I could perform an initial search with git log --grep and then pipe to some further processing step to filter down, but since I'm ultimately just interested in the commit hash, doing it that way would be much less elegant.

(In case anyone comes along and notices this bug, don't worry—I've got a ([^0-9]|$) at the end of the regex to block things like Fix-1234. I just omitted it from the question for the sake of focusing on what I was trying to achieve.)

git log --oneline | grep " Fix-123"

git log --oneline prints one line for every commit in the format "hash 1st line of the message". grep filters by the message.
To grep for message that guaranteed to start with the search text:
git log --pretty=oneline --no-abbrev-commit | grep "^[a-z0-9]\{40\} Fix-123"

git log --pretty=oneline --no-abbrev-commit prints hashes in full length (40 characters); grep "^[a-z0-9]\{40\}" searches (actually, skips) these hashes.

Yeah, this approach is legit and might be what I end up resorting to. It'll still require an additional step of processing to pull out the hashes from the result, which I was hoping to avoid but is definitely not the end of the world. I'm a bit concerned about performance; from my testing, it seems like using git's --grep flag is somewhat faster than piping log output to grep (we have a large commit history), and this is the kind of script where people will appreciate saving a couple seconds per run. But this is workable if there's really no way to get the built-in --grep to work.

@hexaflexagonal git log --grep greps entire commit messages, no way to just grep inside the 1st line, so this is the end of your quest in that direction. "additional step of processing to pull out the hashes from the result" | cut -c1-40 (if full hashes), | cut -f1 -d" " to extract the 1st space-separated field, | awk "{print \$1}".

Don't use {40} here because it only matches SHA-1 repositories.  Do ^[a-f0-9]+ Fix-123.

Oh yeah, I know the whole message is checked—I was more wondering if there was some flag or other way I could adjust the command to create an anchor in the regex for the beginning of the message, rather than the beginning of a line. I know it's simple enough to cut the results, just thought it would be neat to use rev-list directly. But yeah, it sounds like my quest here is fruitless—I don't think I'm cut out for shell programming, everything feels so inelegant  Thank you for your help!

Another, completely different approach — use commit-callback of git-filter-repo in read-only mode, check every commit's message, print commit's hash:
git filter-repo --dry-run --commit-callback "
if re.match(b'^Fix-123', commit.message):
    print(commit.original_id)
"

Please be warned this is Python, not grep, and the syntax for regular expressions is slightly different; see the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax
The second warning — all strings in git filter-repo callbacks are byte-strings, if you know Python 3.
